# ethzasl_message_transport stack (for UDP Multicast) installation problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking to use UDP multicasting approach for communication, I found one stack with 'udpmulti_transport' package which does that.

http://www.ros.org/browse/stack.php?name=ethzasl_message_transport

I have been having problem installing this stack, have cloned it from the repository, and added the folder to Ros Package path.
When I try to install it ( rosmake --rosdep-install ) I get error in the packages which seems to be c++ coding error.

pakage udpmulti_transport

```
  ***udpmulti_publisher.h:30: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘&’ token***
```

then have similar error in sharedmem_transport
Is there something wrong in the stack or I am making some mistake.
PS: running ROS electric

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27684/ethzasl_message_transport-stack-(for-udp-multicast)-installation-problem/) by [sj haque](https://answers.ros.org/users/1584/sj-haque/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found the problem. Evidently ROS electric has some issues with class ros::Message. Its working fine in Diamondback.

---

Originally posted by [sj haque](https://answers.ros.org/users/1584/sj-haque/) with karma: 46 on 2012-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0